# How can I prevent clang-format from indenting a macro?

Tags: clang-format

How can I prevent `clang-format` from indenting the below macro and its assignment?

Definition:

```
#define DESKTOPCHANGE(K,N) \
{MOD, K, changeworkspace, {.i=N}}, \
{MOD | SHIFT, K, sendtoworkspace, {.i=N}},
```

becomes:

```
#define DESKTOPCHANGE(K, N) \
    {MOD, K, changeworkspace, {.i = N}}, \
        {MOD | SHIFT, K, sendtoworkspace, {.i = N}}
```

Usage:

```
static key keys[] = {
    DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_1, 0)
    DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_2, 1)
    DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_3, 2)
    DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_4, 3)
    DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_5, 4)};
```

becomes:

```
static key keys[] = {DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_1, 0) DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_2, 1)
                         DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_3, 2) DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_4, 3)
                             DESKTOPCHANGE(XK_5, 4)}
```

I tried some of the [options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), but can't figure out the correct one. Is there a general way to **turn off** all the **alignments**, and turn them **on only** if **required**?

Here is the [source](https://github.com/venam/2bwm/blob/master/config.h) code from Github. I have modified it to be the way it is in the above snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three answers:

1. Macros like this are bad style, and it would be better to fix the macro to not include the trailing comma. Then you wouldn't have to worry about `clang-format` (or any other formatting tool) misunderstanding the code.
2. With `clang-format` 6.0.0, you can achieve your desired formatting using this:

   ```
   BasedOnStyle: WebKit
   ContinuationIndentWidth: 0
   ```

   Alternatively, if you don't want to base your formatting on the `WebKit` style, this will get you most of the way there:

   ```
   AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
   BinPackParameters: false
   ContinuationIndentWidth: 0
   ```

   The key to this is the `ContinuationIndentWidth` option, documented [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). But, unfortunately, I don't think you really want this answer, because setting `ContinuationIndentWidth: 0` will probably make other code ugly and unreadable.
3. If you already have your code formatted the way you want, and you want to disable `clang-format` from affecting a particular chunk of code, you can surround it with `// clang-format on` and `// clang-format off`. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code) for details.

Comment: Agree, 1 is the best solution :-) Thanks for letting us know about other options!